# Cursor for loop using a selection instead of a table ( Oracle )

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm writing a procedure to fill up a child table from a parent table. The child table however has more fields than the parent table ( as it should be ). I've conjured a cursor which point to a selection, which is essentially a join of multiple tables.
Here's the code I got so far :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Pop_occ_lezione
AS
x Lezione%rowtype;
CURSOR cc IS 
WITH y as(
            SELECT  Codice_corso, 
                    nome_modulo, 
                    Data_inizio_ed_modulo diem, 
                    Giorno_lezione, 
                    ora_inizio_lezione o_i, 
                    ora_fine_lezione o_f, 
                    anno, 
                    id_cdl, 
                    nome_sede, 
                    locazione_modulo loc
            FROM    lezione 
                    join ( select id_cdl, anno, codice_corso from corso ) using (codice_corso)
                    join ( select codice_corso, locazione_modulo from modulo ) using (codice_corso)
                    join ( select nome_sede, id_cdl from cdl  ) using (id_cdl)
            WHERE
                case
                    when extract (month from Data_inizio_ed_modulo) < 9 then extract (year from Data_inizio_ed_modulo) - 1
                    else extract (year from Data_inizio_ed_modulo)
                    end = extract (year from sysdate+365)
        )
SELECT *
FROM y
WHERE sem_check(y.diem,sysdate+365) = 1;
--
BEGIN
FETCH cc into x;
EXIT when cc%NOTFOUND;
INSERT INTO Occr_lezione 
VALUES (
            x.Codice_corso,
            x.Nome_modulo,
            x.diem,x.giorno_lezione,
            x.Ora_inizio_lezione,
            to_date(to_char(next_day(sysdate,x.Giorno_lezione),'DD-MM-YYYY') || to_char(x.Ora_inizio_lezione,' hh24:mi'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'),
            to_date(to_char(next_day(sysdate,x.Giorno_lezione),'DD-MM-YYYY') || to_char(x.Ora_fine_lezione,' hh24:mi'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'),
            x.nome_sede,
            0,
            x.loc
        );
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

But of course it won't work, because the variable x has the type of my initial table row, which has less columns then my selection. Unfortunately As far as I know a rowtype variable is needed to cycle trough a cursor, in order to fetch data from it. Can you see the contradiction? How can I change the code? Is there a certain type of variable which can be crafted to reflect a row from my query result? Or maybe a way to cycle trough the data in the cursor without using a support variable? Or maybe something entirely different? Please let me know.

Ok, so as suggested I tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Occr_lezione(
                         Codice_corso,
                         Nome_modulo,
                         Data_inizio_ed_modulo,
                         Giorno_lezione,
                         Ora_inizio_lezione,
                         Ora_fine_lezione,
                         Anno,
                         Id_cdl,
                         Nome_sede,
                         Locazione_modulo
                        )
WITH y as(
            SELECT  Codice_corso, 
                    Nome_modulo, 
                    Data_inizio_ed_modulo, 
                    Giorno_lezione, 
                    Ora_inizio_lezione, 
                    Ora_fine_lezione, 
                    Anno, 
                    Id_cdl, 
                    Nome_sede, 
                    Locazione_modulo
            FROM    Lezione 
                    join ( select Id_cdl, Anno, Codice_corso from Corso ) using (codice_corso)
                    join ( select Codice_corso, Locazione_modulo from Modulo ) using (Codice_corso)
                    join ( select Nome_sede, Id_cdl from Cdl  ) using (id_cdl)
            WHERE
                case
                    when extract (month from Data_inizio_ed_modulo) < 9 then extract (year from Data_inizio_ed_modulo) - 1
                    else extract (year from Data_inizio_ed_modulo)
                    end = extract (year from sysdate+365)
        )
SELECT *
FROM y
WHERE sem_check(y.Data_inizio_ed_modulo,sysdate+365) = 1;
END;
/
```

But it says PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "LOCAZIONE_MODULO": invalid identifier

which isn't true, because the query return a table in which such column is present... am I missing something?
The code is compiled with no errors, it occurs when I try to fire the procedure.
In the table Occr_lezione as you can see:

```
CREATE TABLE Occr_lezione (
Codice_corso                varchar2(20)    NOT NULL,
Nome_modulo                 varchar2(50)    NOT NULL,
Data_inizio_ed_modulo       date            NOT NULL,
Giorno_lezione              number(1)       NOT NULL,
Ora_inizio_lezione          date            NOT NULL,
Data_inizio_occr_lezione    date,
Data_fine_occr_lezione      date            NOT NULL,
Nome_sede                   varchar2(30)    NOT NULL,
Num_aula                    varchar2(3)     NOT NULL,
Tipo_aula                   varchar2(20)    NOT NULL,
--
CONSTRAINT fk_Occr_lezione_lezione  FOREIGN KEY (Codice_corso,Nome_modulo,Data_inizio_ed_modulo,Giorno_lezione,Ora_inizio_lezione) REFERENCES Lezione(Codice_corso,Nome_modulo,Data_inizio_ed_modulo,Giorno_lezione,Ora_inizio_lezione) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_Occr_lezione_aula     FOREIGN KEY (Nome_sede,Num_aula,Tipo_aula)  REFERENCES Aula(Nome_sede,Num_aula,Tipo_aula) ON DELETE SET NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Occr_lezione          PRIMARY KEY (Codice_corso,Nome_modulo,Data_inizio_ed_modulo,Giorno_lezione,Ora_inizio_lezione,Data_inizio_occr_lezione),
CHECK       ( trunc(Data_inizio_occr_lezione) = trunc(Data_fine_occr_lezione) ), -- data inizio = data fine // prenotazione giornaliera
CHECK       ( Data_inizio_occr_lezione < Data_fine_occr_lezione ) -- ora inizio < ora fine // coerenza temporale
```

there is not a column named Locazione_modulo, however the last column Tipo_aula as the same type and size of Locazione modulo :

```
CREATE TABLE Modulo (
Codice_corso        varchar2(20)    NOT NULL,
Nome_modulo         varchar2(50),
Locazione_modulo    varchar2(20)    NOT NULL,
--
CONSTRAINT fk_Modulo_Corso  FOREIGN KEY(Codice_corso) REFERENCES Corso(Codice_corso) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT pk_Modulo        PRIMARY KEY(Codice_corso,Nome_modulo),
CHECK       (Locazione_modulo IN ('Aula','Laboratorio','Conferenze'))
);
```

So it should be irrelevant, right?

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?  Is the compiler complaining that there is no `LOCAZIONE_MODULO` column in `Occr_lezione`?  Or is it complaining about one of the two references to `LOCAZIONE_MODULO` in your `SELECT` statement?  Since you haven't provided any table definitions (and since you're not using any table aliases in your queries to identify which columns are coming from which tables), it's hard to guess where the error is coming from.

Comment: The compiler works, but when i try to fire the procedure i get this error.

Comment: ORA-00904 is a compilation error not a runtime error.  Unless your actual procedure is doing something with dynamic SQL that you're not showing here, I can't imagine how you're not getting a compilation error but then you are getting a compilation error at runtime.  I would strongly wager that your `CREATE PROCEDURE` call is generating an error but perhaps whatever client application you're using isn't showing it to you or isn't making it apparent enough for you to notice.

Comment: i'm using simple oracle 11g express edition on sqlplus terminal. As matter of fact, i'm an idiot. It is a compilation error. Sorry i'm a little tired 1:24 here !

Comment: i don't know why it occur tough.

Comment: You're getting an error because there is no `Locazione_modulo` column in the `Occr_lezione` table.  The list of columns in your `INSERT INTO Occr_lezione( <<column list>> )` need to be columns in the `Occr_lezione` table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73122/discussion-between-darkpirate-and-justin-cave).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use explicit cursors, you can declare `x` to be of type `cc%rowtype`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Pop_occ_lezione
AS
  CURSOR cc IS ...
  x cc%rowtype;
...
```

Unless you are using explicit cursors because you want to be able to explicitly fetch the data into local collections that you can leverage later on in your procedure, code using implicit cursors tends to be preferrable.  That eliminates the need to `FETCH` and `CLOSE` the cursor or to write an `EXIT` condition and it implicitly does a bulk fetch to minimize context shifts.

```
BEGIN
  FOR x IN cc
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO Occr_lezione ...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Of course, in either case, I would hope that you'd choose more meaningful names for your local variables-- `x` and `cc` don't tell you anything about what the variables are doing.

If all you are doing is taking data from one set of tables and inserting it into another table, it would be more efficient to write a single `INSERT` statement rather than coding a PL/SQL loop.

```
INSERT INTO Occr_lezione( <<column list>> )
  SELECT <<column list>>
    FROM <<tables you are joining together in the cursor definition>>
   WHERE <<conditions from your cursor definition>>
```

Comment: wow, thank you, i just figured out that i could use the cursor as a rowtype but didn't know that inserting directly from a query was possible, thanks for the information !

Comment: so, as you may notice i used aliases in the selection, but i suppose that i can't go with them in the insert, because they are not processed yet. Is that right ?

Comment: @darkpirate - I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you're asking.  If you structure your `SELECT` query using a CTE (or inline view or something similar) you can still define aliases like you are doing and you can use them in the outer query.  Whether adding aliases is useful when you're doing a single `INSERT ... SELECT` is a question you'd need to answer.

Comment: You're right. in my case are not that necessary, i've updated the post by the way, it will be wonderful if you could look at it :)